# php scrape to write to mysql database error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, scrape

first function is this

```
              $output_csv = fopen( "Poems.csv", "w" );
..code here
               $poem_text = trim($pre->innertext);

               $poem_text = str_replace('"','',$poem_text);

               $poem_text = html_entity_decode($poem_text);

               $poem_text = str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x1a")," ",$poem_text);
...code here
              $p

    oem_data = array( $author_names[$i], $poem_names[$i], $poem_text, $poem_urls[$i] );
                 fputcsv( $output_csv, $poem_data );   
...code here
```

the last function is

```
function writeQuotestoDb() {
  $input_csv = fopen( "Poems.csv", "r" );
  $author_names = array();
  $poem_names = array();
  $poem_text = array();
  $poem_urls = array();

  while (($columns = fgetcsv($input_csv, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    array_push( $author_names, $columns[0] );
    array_push( $poem_names,  $columns[1] );
    array_push( $poem_text, $columns[2]);
    array_push( $poem_urls,  $columns[3] );
  }
  fclose( $input_csv );

  //$dbh = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'poetiv', 'alegado' );
  $dbh = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '' );
  mysql_select_db( 'test', $dbh );
  mysql_query("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS `poem2` (
             `id` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
             `author_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
              `poem_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
              `poem_text` text,
              `poem_url` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL
             ) ENGINE = MYISAM");
    mysql_query("TRUNCATE `poem2`");     
    for ( $i=0; $i<count($author_names); $i++ ) {
        $poems[$i] = substr($poems[$i],7,(strlen($poems[$i])-14));
        $poems[$i] = str_replace('"','',$poems[$i]);
        $query = "insert into poem2 (author_name,poem_name,poem_text,poem_url) values 
        ('" . $author_names[$i] . "', '" . $poem_names[$i]."', '" . $poem_text[$i]."', '" .$poem_urls[$i] ."')";
        if( !mysql_query($query) ) { echo $query; 
            }
        }
    echo count($author_names)." rows....successfully db updated";
    //SELECT count(*) FROM `quotes` WHERE criteria = 'Baby Quotes'
 }
```

i get an error like this one example

> 'Salve magna parens frugum Saturnia tellus, Magna virm! tibi res
>   antiqu laudis et artis Aggredior, sanctos ausus recludere fontes.
>   Virg. Geor. 2.   1           While you, my Lord, the rural shades
>   admire, 2     And from Britannia's public posts retire, 3     Nor
>   longer, her ungrateful sons to please, 4     For their advantage
>   sacrifice your ease;  5           Me into foreign realms my fate
>   conveys, 6     Through nations fruitful of immortal lays, 7     Where
>   the soft seas

The ' in Britannia's is not escaped

im not sure if it needs to be ''or \'

but i would like to know how to solve this error and be able to complete to write all in the sql db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on your values before plugging them into a query.
Better yet, get with the times and use the [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) extension with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I read that I have to connect to sql before performing mysql_real_escape_string . In my situation I scrape the data and save them in Poems.csv and to write to sql db i read the info from Poem.csv. How will I be able to put the mysql_real_escape_string in the first function mentioned in the post?

Comment: You don't use it when writing the data to the file, you use it when constructing your `$query` variable! Please read the PHP manual for examples on using these functions.

Comment: in this case how would you put it :)

Comment: As simple as `"INSERT INTO poem2 (author_name, ...) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($author_names[$i]) ...`. But really, look into PDO and prepared statements!

Answer (score 3):

You should be using PHP's [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function to escape your string you are inserting.

Comment: I read that I have to connect to sql before performing mysql_real_escape_string . In my situation I scrape the data and save them in Poems.csv and to write to sql db i read the info from Poem.csv. How will I be able to put the mysql_real_escape_string in the first function mentioned in the post?

Comment: You simply call this function on your insert statement after you have established the connection, but before you run the statment.  Ex. $query = mysql_real_escape_string( $query );  mysql_query($query);

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I pass all of my data through, before inserting it into my database...

```
private function makeSqlSafe($data){
  $str = @trim($data);
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $data = stripslashes($data);
  }
  if(!is_numeric($data)){
    $data = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."'";
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I read that I have to connect to sql before performing mysql_real_escape_string . In my situation I scrape the data and save them in Poems.csv and to write to sql db i read the info from Poem.csv. How will I be able to put the mysql_real_escape_string in the first function mentioned in the post?

Comment: Bundling Magic Quotes treatment into `makeSqlSafe` functions seems like a bad idea. You should strip Magic Quote inflicted slashes regardless of what's going to happen with the data when you first touch the `$_POST` array at all. What if you want to do something else with the data *and* put it in a database. You'll end up stripping slashes twice (which may alter data drastically) or you have to work around your self inflicted problem. Also, don't use `@`. Also, you're never using `$str`. Overall, this is not a good function.